# Google keep: Copying image from one note to another

Tags: images, copy-paste, google-keep, copying

I am using Google keep on an Android 11 device.

I am wondering how I can copy an image in Google keep from one Google keep note to another.

How can I do this?

I'm asking because I received an image via WhatsApp and could not share it to a specific already existing Google keep note but had to share it to new Google keep note.

So, I shared it to a new Google keep note.

However, when I selected the image by long pressing on it in Google keep, and then selected copy from the three dots in the upper right hand corner I could copy it, but then did not find the way of pasting it to the other note that already contained images there.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a possible workaround if you use Gboard as it can paste copied images.

1. Launch Google Keep and open the shared note (with image) you just saved. Copy the image.
2. Open the note where the copied image should be pasted. Press on the note to open Gboard, then paste the image.

Comment: It is a bit of a shortcoming that one must use Gboard meaning that if another keyboard is used this functionality may not be available.